# delphi, indy10 tcp audio streaming

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, indy10

i am trying to make an application that use video/audio streaming through TCP connection, i already done the video streaming with indy10 component(idtcpserver and idtcpclient), is it possible do the same thing but with audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

TCP is just data channel. It is totally agnostic to what kind of data is transferred to it. HTML pages, programs, video, audio - whatever. It is just a data channel within TCP protocol.

However, "streaming" usually means "near to real time". If some frames of video or audio did not arrived during few seconds - they better be skipped and forgotten and newer music or video be played. You would not want your Skype conversation suddenly stuck for a minute and then playback all that minute to you, just because of few seconds network jam. You'd better loose a word or two and then either recover by context or ask the correspondent to repeat. Thus TCP with built-in retransmissions and usually not very large buffers is not a perfect choice for multimedia streaming. Usually UDP + application-implemented integrity control is better choice for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the unit VFW. With avistream, you join video + sound in a compressed stream.

Comment: Video for Windows ? 16-bit interface designed in 1993 ? and hastily updates to 32-bit but never redesigned ? why should he ? Better he use DirectX as modern players do.

Comment: I know there is a directshow, but initially it should check the basics ... join compressed audio + video and then send via net.

Comment: But that is not the basics. That is one more potential trouble: would obsolete VFW support th modern formats you'd toss to it or not? would it have some bitrot-nduced bug in modern Windows or not ? etc. If you would want to convert audio to video - better prepare the file using VirtualDub or AviDemux or such and then try transfering the readymade file

Comment: AFAIK virtualdub uses VFW api itself ;-)... so even though VFW is obsolete, it is still used, and is a very much simpler API to understand than MediaFoundation or DirectShow.